# UItextView background colours Linespacing area too

Tags: swift, uitextview, highlight, nsattributedstring, line-spacing

I am trying to replicate the text highlight (Not Search Text Highlight) in my UIText View. But I am Stuck with the colouring in the linespacing as well. How Can I rectify this ?

Current situation:

[image]

Desired Outcome:

[image]

I have added the following attributes to my UiTextview's Attributed Text

For Paragraph Line Spacing I have used the following

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
```

For Other Attributes I have used the following

```
verseAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue : NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue) : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:CGFloat(20*sizeMultiplier)) ?? 20,        
NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue : NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor.darkGray,
NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue : NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor.blue]
NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue : NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle) : paragraphStyle]
```

Comment: Hi Amith, did you ever figure it out?